# How to create a new marker or list of markers using Google Maps API on REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, event-handling, google-maps-markers

Im trying to create a list of markers on my map, but to create one, we need to use the .Marker object, a it require to specify the map. I got all my configuration on the initMap(), and inside the function is easy to create a marker, but when i try to use an event like "click" on a buttom, to create a marker, im not quite sure how to do it. 
One thing is that i decided to implement the map using pure JS on a ReactJS Component, im not using the react-google-maps library.

The Map is working fine, but i would like to now how to create markers, because my plan is to bring and array from the DB, on that way it would render specific points depending on a event.

```
class MapComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.renderMap(); 
    }
 renderMap=()=>{
     loadScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBTOonRy8VwjMLryGyfmUOAexCgrQI9m0A&callback=initMap')
     window.initMap = this.initMap; 
    }
 initMap=()=> {
        let uluru = {lat: 9.024645, lng:-79.531094 }; // eslint-disable-next-line
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: uluru,
            mapTypeId: 'satellite'
          };
        let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); // eslint-disable-next-line

    }

createMarker=()=>{ 
    console.log('works')
    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 9.024645, lng:-79.531094}, map: this.initMap.map} )
    return marker
}

    render(){
    const { points, logged } = this.props
    if(!logged) return <Redirect to='signIn' />

        return(
            <main>
                <div id="map">
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.createMarker}> Click </button>
            </main>

        );}

}

function loadScript(url){
    var index = window.document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var script = window.document.createElement('script'); 
    script.src = url; 
    script.async = true; 
    script.defer = true; 
    index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index); 


}

const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
    return {
    points: state.firestore.ordered.points,
    logged: state.firebase.auth.uid
    }
}
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps), 
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection:'points' }, 
    ])
)(MapComponent)
```

Comment: Do you get 'works' in your console?

Comment: Yes, the function fires right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're not returning in your initMap function:

```
 initMap=()=> {
    let uluru = {lat: 9.024645, lng:-79.531094 }; // eslint-disable-next-line
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: uluru,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
      };
    let this.myMap = window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); // eslint-disable-next-line

}
```

and call it like so:

```
createMarker=()=>{ 
    console.log('works')
    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 9.024645, lng:-79.531094}, map: this.myMap} )
    return marker
}
```

Comment: Yes, got your point, but i don't want to initialize the map instance every time i create a marker, it will cause a lot of innecesary hits on the API

Comment: Ok edited, now you assign the map to a class property, let me know if this works!